# Delete rows from report based upon specific field value

Tags: ssrs

I have found how to hide rows based upon a specific field value.

But is it possible to actually delete the rows from the report and not just hide them?

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it looks as if the trick was to get a row count of the rows where Status = "OK" and compare that to the count of all rows.

If they are equal then there are no warning messages and we display the message row.

If they are not equal, then there are warnings and we do not display the message row.

And the trick to doing all that was to sum the rows with a status of OK like so:

=iif(countrows()<>sum(iif(Fields!ALERT_VALUE.Value=”OK”,1,0)),true,false)

Thanks to my friend Charles for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of `DELETE` for a report itself, specifically **SSRS**, because a report is meant to be read-only. If by `DELETE` you mean you don't want to bring those rows into your report's dataset at all, then you need to filter the dataset appropriately to eliminate the rows upstream.

For example if your dataset is a SQL query, you can add a predicate in the `WHERE` clause of that query to filter out the data (or if it's a stored procedure you could do the same via a parameter). We'd need to see the query that populates your **SSRS** report's dataset.

---

If instead, you're asking how to have a "delete button" in an **SSRS** report, so a user can choose which rows to **delete from your database**, then that's a little more complicated.

It would require you creating a stored procedure that deletes from the underlying tables appropriately and takes in parameter(s) of the key(s) for the rows being deleted. Then you'd make that a hidden parameter of your report, and would have to add a column to your report with a link that has an expression that references the report itself but with the additional hidden parameter. Then it would re-run the same report but passing in the key of the row that the link was clicked on to the stored procedure, so it knew which row to delete from your database, before returning the rest of the rows needed for the report.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't work on the stored proc that feeds this report as it feeds others as well. That is why I was trying to work in the report. The rows in the report have a status. In most cases the status is "OK". In other rows one of several warnings are displayed. I have hidden rows with the "OK" status so only rows with warnings are displayed. But in the event that there are no warnings and only "OKs" (hidden) I would like to display a message indicating that there are no warnings. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: @SteveConnelly That's a more realistic goal that's accomplishable in **SSRS**. You can add a textbox to your report above the Tablix, with the message you want to display, with the `CanGrow` property set to `True` and toggle the visibility with the same kind of expression you're using for your rows, but set it's visibility to `True` when the count of the warning rows is 0.

Comment: Not sure that I get that. Sorry but I am pretty new to this so thanks for your patience. The expression that I use to hide all the "OK" rows is: =Fields!ALERT_VALUE.Value = "OK".

Comment: This only displays rows with warnings. If there are no warnings, then there are only the column headers. I added a static row with the desired message below that and I am trying to get it to display when there are no warning rows. I am not sure how CanGrow helps with that.

Comment: What I attempted to do with the show/hide for the message row was to make an expression that gets a row count of rows where the status is OK and see if that is the same as the row count of all rows. This is what I have tried so far without success: =(COUNT(Fields!ALERT_VALUE.Value.Equals("OK")) <> COUNT(Fields!CA_ID.Value)), though I am not sure if it should be = or <>, I have tried both.

Comment: I looked at this again. I think the problem is I don't know how to do the expression for the various values of warnings to be zero.